# Email Notification of Collabnet Subversion Edge Stack Software Updates

Tags: svn, stack, auto-update, subversion-edge

I am looking for a way to receive email notifications when an update is available for the Collabnet Subversion Edge stack.  I just logged into the web interface for Edge and noticed that an update was released on August 29.

I had initially thought that the updates were "automatic" in the sense that Chrome has automatic updates, but it appears that there [is still user intervention required.](http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&dsMessageId=412766)  This is fine, but I do not log into the web interface often enough to be notified of updates in a timely manner.

It would seem there would be a mailing list or an option in Subversion Edge for this, but I have found neither.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm currently running version 3.1.0-3220.94 of the stack on Windows Server 2008 r2.

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so please give me brutal feedback if I have done anything incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Release Announcements mailing list here:

https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/discussion/do/listForums/projects.svnedge/discussion

You need to be logged in with the account you created to download Subversion Edge.  But you should be able to "Monitor" the Release Announcements list and you will get emails when the releases are announced.

Emails will go to the email address associated with your account.

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I needed!  I'm not sure if you noticed, but it was a comment of yours that I linked to in my question.